# How to access the variables the CMake variables which is already used in CMakelist.txt to a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a CMakelist.txt and I am writing a python script for an another execution now with the python script i need to use the variables which was used in the CMakelists.txt.

In CMakelists.txt I have a variable as

file(STRINGS ${srcfilelist} sourcefilelist)

So how to pass the variable 'sourcefilelist' from CMakelist.txt to *.py script file, How to access the variables from CMake file to a python file.?

thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: modified the question

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to pass variables from the build system, e.g. CMake, to build scripts or the compiler is the environment. Note that environment variables are always strings.

In CMake, you use `set()` command to [set environment variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-environment-variable), e.g.

```
set(ENV{<FOOBAR>} 42)
```

In Python, you can use [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) to access environment variables, e.g.

```
foobar = int(os.environ.get('FOOBAR', 23)) # use 23 if not set
```

Comment: is there any way to import/include the Cmakelists.txt into the python script and use the variables used inside CMakelists.txt?, because there are certain variables which are not assigned inside the CMakelists.txt, and I need to use that variable as well and there are so many variables I need to access which is also used inside CMakelists.txt